# how to reduce error in hypothesis in neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

Suppose you have implemented regularized logistic regression

to classify what object is in an image (i.e., to do object

recognition). However, when you test your hypothesis on a new

set of images, you find that it makes unacceptably large

errors with its predictions on the new images. However, your

hypothesis performs well (has low error) on the

training set. Which of the following are promising steps to

take?

Comment: This exact question is from a ML class. That's very lazy...

Answer (score 0):

The solution by which i myself solved my problem is to get more training samples and reducing features.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is usually referred to as "high variance". In these cases, getting more training data, alone, is not guaranteed to improve your results. As you pointed out in your own reply, reducing the number of features can be a good approach and, as you are using regularized logistic regression, lowering the regularization parameter can help too.

Comment: no, the opposite. overfitting is the same as high variance, high bias means it underfits the training set